# Jenkinsfile Parameters Issue : Issue while running with multiple parameters to bat maven

Tags: java, maven, jenkins-pipeline

I have an issue while running my job through the Jenkins file, whatever parameters I gave its updated in the place where I called it, but when it runs with bat mvn command it tool goal as that of the parameter itself. Suppose I Specified the parameter name is QA from my Jenkins build with parameter and run it ..it complete all the steps except the last one where i have build, bat mvn, it tried to run taking goal and lifecycle as QA instead of clean test-compile.

I have attached the Jenkinfile herewith.

```
pipeline {
agent { label 'TESTING' }

tools {
    maven 'maven'
}
 parameters{
    choice(name: 'ENVIRONMENT' , choices: ['QA' , 'UAT' , 'PREPROD'] , description: '')
    choice(name: 'SUITE' , choices: ['Regression' , 'Smoke'] , description: '')
                  }

stages {

stage('Clone') { 

    steps {
            git branch: 'master' , credentialsId: 'xyzabc' , url: "https://git.xyz.com/project/automation.git"
        }  
       
    }
stage('Git Checkout') {
    steps {
        git(branch: 'development',
            credentialsId: 'xyzabc',
            url: "https://git.xyz.com/project/automation.git")
    }
}

    stage('Build') {
        
        steps {
        echo "parameter name from jenkinsfile Environment is  ${params.ENVIRONMENT}"
        echo "parameter name from jenkinsfile SUITE is ${params.SUITE}"
        bat "mvn clean test-compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass='com.test.mainClass' -Dexec.args='${params.ENVIRONMENT} ${params.SUITE}' -Dexec.classpathScope=test"
            
        }
    }
 }
```

}

ERROR MESSAGE IN JENKINS RUN,

[image]

Comment: It appears you have a typo in your `"mvn clean test-compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.test.mainClass" ...` and forgot to escape your inner `"`. If you escape those characters, does that fix your issue?

Comment: Yes Matt, I tried to put like bat "mvn clean test-compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass='com.test.mainClass' -Dexec.args='${params.ENVIRONMENT} ${params.SUITE}' -Dexec.classpathScope=test"  but still had the same issue.

Comment: Ok please update your question to reflect that you have fixed the typo and the same error results.

Comment: Updated.. Thanks

Comment: Is there any alternate way to make it work..? Thank you in advance.